# Where can I find copies of Bodhayana Vritti and Bodhayana Vritti by Kuresha?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, vishishtadvaita, ramanujacharya

Sri Ramanuja went to Kashmir with Kuresha, his disciple, to read and write commentary on Bramasurtras, based on Bodhayana Vritti which was a short commentary already written on it. He wanted the Bodhayana Vritti from Kashmir libraries, and the local scholars there were not allowing them to take it or even take notes from it. So Ramanuja and Kuresha had to only read from the library. But Kuresha apparently was able to memorise the whole thing and repeat it, on which Ramanuja wrote the commentary Sri Bashyam.

I am curious if we can get copies of the real vritti and the dictated from memory vritti and see if there are any changes or it was word to word replication.

Comment: There are no known surviving copies of Bodhāyana's vṛtti now, afaik. It's lost, like many other śāstras.

Answer (score 0):

- There is no known manuscript of the Bodhayana Vritti.
- There is no known manuscript of the memorized version of the Bodhayana Vritti
- It is unclear if Ramanujacharya / Kuresha actually saw the entire Vritti. The Sribhashya only says that (1) The lengthy Vritti of Bodhayana was abridged by previous Acharyas, and (2) In accordance to this, the sutras will be explained. It is unclear if 'this' refers to the Vritti or the abridgement.
- There are only about ten citations of the Bodhayana Vritti in the Sribhashya they all occur exclusively in the first adhikaraNa.
- About 250 years after Ramanuja, Vedanta Desika has made a couple of references to previously unknown portions of the Bodhayana Vritti.